# Need to collect the first letter of each string in a list and put it all together as a new string

Tags: list, applescript

I have problems to understand how to construct a small AppleScript and would be greatfull if someone could help in modifying it with some explanations about how to make it. I would like to generate from a list of names a code made from the first letter of each names.

My script works but every time the list changes mainly grows then I need to add extra lines to deal with the new added names. I would like that the script looks at every names in the list and returns the new code without to have to work through the script every time.

```
set myList to "Apple Banana Orange Kiwi"

set wordsNumber to the number of words of myList


if wordsNumber = 1 then
    set firstcharacter to first character of first word of myList
    set secondcharacter to second character of first word of myList
    set thirdcharacter to last character of first word of myList


    set generatedCoCode to firstcharacter & secondcharacter & thirdcharacter

    set unmodifiedCoCode to generatedCoCode
    set upperCaseCoCode to do shell script "echo " & unmodifiedCoCode & " | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"
else
    try
        if wordsNumber = 2 then
            set firstcharacter to first character of first word of myList
            set secondcharacter to second character of first word of myList
            set thirdcharacter to first character of second word of myList


            set generatedCoCode to firstcharacter & secondcharacter & thirdcharacter

            set unmodifiedCoCode to generatedCoCode
            set upperCaseCoCode to do shell script "echo " & unmodifiedCoCode & " | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"

        else
            try
                if wordsNumber = 3 then
                    set firstcharacter to first character of first word of myList
                    set secondcharacter to first character of second word of myList
                    set thirdcharacter to first character of third word of myList


                    set generatedCoCode to firstcharacter & secondcharacter & thirdcharacter

                    set unmodifiedCoCode to generatedCoCode
                    set upperCaseCoCode to do shell script "echo " & unmodifiedCoCode & " | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"

                else
                    try
                        if wordsNumber = 4 then
                            set firstcharacter to first character of first word of myList
                            set secondcharacter to first character of second word of myList
                            set thirdcharacter to first character of third word of myList
                            set fourthcharacter to first character of fourth word of myList

                            set generatedCoCode to firstcharacter & secondcharacter & thirdcharacter & fourthcharacter

                            set unmodifiedCoCode to generatedCoCode
                            set upperCaseCoCode to do shell script "echo " & unmodifiedCoCode & " | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"

                        else
                            try
                                if wordsNumber = 5 then
                                    set firstcharacter to first character of first word of myList
                                    set secondcharacter to first character of second word of myList
                                    set thirdcharacter to first character of third word of myList
                                    set fourthcharacter to first character of fourth word of myList
                                    set fifthcharacter to first character of fifth word of myList

                                    set generatedCoCode to firstcharacter & secondcharacter & thirdcharacter & fourthcharacter & fifthcharacter

                                    set unmodifiedCoCode to generatedCoCode
                                    set upperCaseCoCode to do shell script "echo " & unmodifiedCoCode & " | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"


                                end if
                            end try
                        end if
                    end try
                end if
            end try
        end if
    end try
end if
```

Comment: "Apple Banana Orange Kiwi" **is not** a [list](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_lexical_conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH214-SW15), it just a text string. This is a list: `{"Apple", "Banana", "Orange, "Kiwi"}`

Comment: yes you are of course right sorry about that I'll try to be more thorough next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the code to

```
set myList to "Apple Banana Orange Kiwi"
set wordsNumber to the number of words of myList

set generatedCoCod to ""
if wordsNumber = 1 then
    if length of myList = 3 then
        set generatedCoCod to reverse of characters of myList
    else
        tell myList to set generatedCoCod to text 1 thru 2 & text -1
    end if
else if wordsNumber = 2 then
    tell myList to set generatedCoCod to text 1 thru 2 of 1st word & text 1 of 2nd word
else
    repeat with aWord in words of myList
        set generatedCoCod to generatedCoCod & first character of aWord
    end repeat
end if
set upperCaseCoCode to do shell script "echo " & generatedCoCod & " | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"
```

For the cases `wordsNumber >= 3` it uses a repeat loop to append the first character of each word to `generatedCoCod`. Finally it capitalizes the string.

Comment: Thank you very much did not know how to create this... been trying for long time you help a lot thanks.

Comment: One little question though when I have only 1 word in my list I would like to get the first 2 characters followed by the last character if the word has more than 3 characters but if it has only 3 characters I would like to get the characters reversed (Last come fist...) then if we have only 2 words I would like to get the first 2 characters of the the first word followed by the first character of the second word. for all other options your script is great.